# Sort options for sorting letters with dots and numbers

Tags: bash, sorting, join, chain

I would like to merge two files with `join`
File1 is like:

```
Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Infantis   lcl|CP052796.1_prot_QJV25804.1_4153
...
```

And file2 is:

```
...
Prot    lcl|CP052796.1_prot_QJV25804.1_4153 98.701  100
...
```

And I would like to get a file like this:

```
Prot Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Infantis lcl|CP052796.1_prot_QJV25804.1_4153 98.701 100
```

I tried with `join -1 2 -2 2 -o 2.1 1.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 file1 file2` but join gives warning "join: file2: is not sorted".

I tried to sort both files before do it, with `sort -k2,2 file1` for example, but it doesn't work. Any idea to sort this type of chain?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate about the logic how the output line is composed?  Your input files and the expected output do not match. Where does the portion `QJV25804.1_4153 98.701 100` come from?

Comment: It is a blast result @tshiono. ```QJV25804.1_4153``` is the protein identifier, while the numbers are blast identity and covarege. They are separated. Input files and the expected output do not match because I pasted the first two lines, but the files has a lot of lines.

Comment: Check the last edit @tshiono

Answer (score 1):

If `awk` is your option, would you please try:

```
awk '
    # the following block processes File1
    NR==FNR {
        f1[$2] = $1     # associate the 1st field with 2nd field in File1
        next
    }
    # the following block processes File2
    f1[$2] {            # if the 2nd field is found in File1
        print $1, f1[$2], $2, $3, $4
    }
' File1 File2
```

Output with the provided sample:

```
Prot Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Infantis lcl|CP052796.1_prot_QJV25804.1_4153 98.701 100
```